# Video mode list in Windows

Tags: windows, video, screen-resolution, xrandr

How do I get a list of all available video modes in Windows? I would like to see both resolutions and refresh rates. Under Linux I would use xrandr without arguments which give me this perfect list:

```
1024x768       60.0 +  120.0     85.0     75.0     70.1  
4096x2160      24.0     24.0  
3840x2160      30.0     25.0     24.0     30.0     24.0  
2048x2048      60.0  
1920x1440      75.0     60.0  
1856x1392      75.0     60.0  
1792x1344      75.0     60.0  
2048x1152      60.0  
1920x1200      84.9     74.9     60.0*
1024x768i      87.1
```

I would also be nice to see whether a mode is interlaced or progressive. Xrandr will append a lower case 'i' for all interlaced modes (see last line above).

Comment: Is this a programming question? Do you want to code a program that does this or are you just looking for a existing program you can use?

Comment: Generally, both would be fine. Preferrably I would like to write some Python code. I only need the list as a file or stdout. I need to run some tests on displays that I want to automate.

Answer (score 0):

When programming with the Windows API you would use the [`EnumDisplaySettings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162611(v=vs.85).aspx) function in a loop to get all the modes. Call `EnumDisplayDevices` first if you need to list the modes of a specific GPU/Monitor. Call `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx` if you want to change the mode...